# BitBucket - can we track tasks on pull requests?

Tags: bitbucket

We'd like to be able to see when tasks are marked as completed on a pull request. A list of completed lists, like the list of pending tasks, would be ideal, but just some sort of audit log showing them getting marked would be fine too.

Does anyone know if this kind of view is supported in any way?